# Вопрос по формам/

Tags: css, html5, css3

Читал в статье что при создании формы никогда не надо label заменяйте на placeholder, это важное дополнение, но никак не замена. Почему так? Вёдь при обоих случаях мы видим что от нас требуют ввести в форму? Или тут забота о людях которые через скринридеры ходят?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, label и placeholder служат разным целям. Label - для указания названия поля, что надо вводить. Placeholder - подсказка и пример, как это вводить. Но для экономии места часто указывают только placeholder. У этого есть минусы:

1) Как Вы отметили, проблема со скринридерами;

2) placeholder исчезает, когда человек начинает вводить значение, и это неудобно;

3) неприменимо в тех формах, у которых первое поле получает фокус сразу после загрузки страницы;

4) старые IE не поддерживают placeholder; старее IE 10, если я не ошибаюсь;

5) более семантически правильно будет с тегом label, чем без него.

PS Я не профи, ответила как сама понимаю.